# How to serialize a list with Jackson without the list name?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using this code:

```
XmlMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
    objectMapper.configure( ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true );
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    String xml = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(report);
```

To serialize this class:

```
class Report {

   List<Item> items;
}
```

The list of items is in an element called "items":

```
<Report>
<items>
<item>
</item>
<item>
...
```

I would like it to serialize without the "items" element:

```
<Report>
<item>
</item>
<item>
...
```

Any suggestions how I can do this with jackson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a slight variation on the @Andreas answer.

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "ignoredName", useWrapping = false)
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "item")
private List<Item> itemList;
```

Use the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` annotation to identify that it is a list of stuff
and you don't want a wrapper element.
Use the `@JacksonXmlProperty` annotation to identify the element name.

This will cause a repetition of `<item>` xml elements in your output; one per entry in the `itemList` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Add the [`@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html) annotation, specifying that you don't want a wrapper:

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
List<Item> items;
```